# Is this sentence confusing?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

I found this sentence in [a New York Times article](https://mobile.nytimes.com/2018/05/12/upshot/these-95-apartments-promised-affordable-rent-in-san-francisco-then-6580-people-applied.html):

> They rented not so much a home as a fraction of one.

It seemed confusing to me that I spent minutes trying to understand it. And here are my versions which I think are better:

> They didn’t rent a home so much as a fraction of one.
>
> They rented not a home but rather a fraction of one.

Is the original meaning too confusing? And are my revisions ok?

Comment: *home* has a very broad meaning; in general it can refer to any place you live regularly. Or figuratively (home sweet home). So what they were promised as a "home" (physically) was far less than what they got.

Answer (score 1):

Native speakers wouldn't find the original sequence from NYT at all "confusing".

It's perfectly familiar (if somewhat stylised) phrasing, where the noun phrase construction *not so much X as Y* carries the highly specific implication ***expected*** = X, **reality** = Y.

OP's first attempt at "improvement" *(They **didn’t** rent a home so much as a fraction of one)* doesn't work so well as the original because it erroneously links negating ***n't = not*** closer to the verb *(rent)* rather than its true referent *(a home)*. That "misplaced" negation weakens the amusing/unexpected contrast intended by the writer, because it puts the "focus" in the wrong place.

To my mind, the second rephrasing *(They rented not a home but rather a fraction of one)* also falls short of the mark because it lacks any strong allusion to that "expectation vs reality" clash. You can tell this by considering something like *I drive not a diesel but rather a petrol car*. Admittedly, that's rather affected phrasing, but the point is this construction can be used without implying that the speaker might have been *expected* to drive a diesel (feasibly the speaker only mentioned diesels at at simply because they'd been referred to earlier in the conversation).

---

TL;DR: There's nothing syntactically "wrong" with either of OP's alternatives, but for a competent native speaker they're not so effective as the original. And it may be worth pointing out that NYT's [*target readership*](https://www.bbc.com/education/guides/zps4qty/revision/5) is competent native speakers, not people who are learning English in later life.

Comment: Before it seems abstract to me. Now I start to realize the sense of the meaning. “Not so much a home as a fraction of one”, so a fraction is much more. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

At the most basic level, we can think of a house as a structure containing a bunch of rooms. Metaphorically speaking, a fraction of a house would be just one or two rooms. Then, what the passage is saying is that what they were renting was not so much of a house (the entire house), but a fraction of it. Probably just a room. So, they were most likely renting a single room.

Comment: If you look at the linked article, it refers to people who rent a bedroom + shared use of a bathroom and kitchen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find the sentence confusing. I understand it to be equivalent to the two sentences

> They didn't rent a home. They rented a fraction of a home.

The context (a woman who rented a room + shared bathroom and shared kitchen) fits with this interpretation.  Your two glosses are also correct.

Cambridge have a dictionary definition of [not so much sth as sth](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/not-so-much-sth-as-sth)